# Wrong data returned from elasticsearch after recreate the index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, tire

for testing and development reasons we reindex our data from a rails app by deleting an index and recreate with mapping and import existing documents.

But after recreating the index, elasticsearch returns other results than expected and before recreating. If we restart the elasticsearch instance, the results as expected.
This is how we recreate the index.

```
Tire.index indexname do
  delete
  create _mappings
  import _objects
  refresh
end
```

We also checked the search query directly via curl on elastic search, but we got not the expected result. After restarting the elastic search daemon, same query returns expected data.

What have to be done or what is expected of an elasticsearch instance to return correct data after recreating an index with the same name without restarting? We also tried creating new indexes with timestamp names and aliasing the index name to these index, but with same results.

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried deleting the index from Elasticsearch directly and verifying the issue? I wonder if this is some weird caching issue with `Tire` (which I have never used).

Comment: Yes, tried deleting it via curl, created it via tire. Unfortunately, same result. Filtering results are not the same. Restart of elastic search fixes this.